# standardize two categorical variables into same unit

Tags: standardization

I have two categorical variables that I want to add: fruit portions = portions of fruit per day (a portion representing a handful): 1= never to 7=5 or more portions, and fruit juice frequency = how often drink fruit juice per week:1=never, 2=once a month, 3=1-2 times per week to 5=everyday. 
I want to add them into one category but they are in different units. Z-scores wouldn't deal with the difference I don't think, so how can I standardize them to be both either daily or weekly?
thank you

Comment: To meaningfully add them you must effectively make them interval-scaled, so must draw some kind of equivalence both within and across variables -- '*that* much juice, *this* often, is the same as one portion of fruit per day'. How you decide what those various equivalences are isn't really a stats problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, never = never, once a month = 1/30 per day, 1-2 per week = (say) 3/14 per day and so on.

But

1) Fruits - 5 or more portions isn't a number. 
2) Fruit juice frequency per week isn't in portions
3) A portion of juice isn't necessarily equal (in any real sense) to a portion of fruit.

so, you can't really do this.

I think you have to leave them as two variables.

Comment: thank you...would that transformation leave them as categorical or do they become some sort of pseudo-continuous variables? I could truncate 5 or more to 5 portions per day. I know frequency isn't portions but I could work under the assumption that a glass of fruit juice for example is not so different from one portion of fruits?

Comment: also i can't simply add them (i am working in SPSS), so I guess if I do aggregate them I would have to have the new aggregated variable as max (Fruit Portions per day, Fruit Juice per day) ?

Comment: Andreea, this answer clearly states you *cannot* validly aggregate these data (without some further analysis, anyway;  taking the maximum is practically nonsensical.) Note, too, that both variables actually are *ordinal*: they carry more information (via their natural ordering) than merely categorical variables. How you deal with them depends on what role they play in your analysis--as independent or dependent variables--as well as their relationships with other variables, which you will need to discover through exploratory analysis.

Comment: thank you for your reply. These represent my outcome variables. My supervisor has suggested in the past that I could aggregate such variables that represent frequency by taking the maximum of the frequency between the 2 variables, because I cannot simply add them as such. I realise I loose some variance but it seems to me the only way, considering they have different number of categories. Also, in terms of aggregation, the correlation coefficient between the 2 is 0.206, which is quite weak, so might suggest I could add them?

Comment: You can't add them and the maximum makes no sense - they aren't comparable; the maximum of these two variables is going to be nonsense. You can either use both (and have two outcome variables) or just pick one. Sorry to be negative, but this is one of many times when the quote from Ronald Fisher is apropos: "To call in the statistician after the experiment is done may be no more than asking him to perform a post-mortem examination: he may be able to say what the experiment died of."

Comment: Your two variables both represent frequencies, but frequencies of different things (fruits and juices), on different scales (one is in pure frequency, the other is in portions). The fact that the correlation (I hope you used rank correlation) is low is further evidence *against* combining them: They are different things.